# Regex replace keyword with different string by loop (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, expression, preg-replace, preg-match

Let say I have a string

`$content = "hello . wow . cool . yes!";`

It's easy to just replace the dot to another string:

`echo preg_replace("/\./", "<img>", $content);`

so the output is:

`hello <img> wow <img> cool <img> yes!`

however, is there any way to replace it one by one?

for example, I have an array and would like to insert them into the string.

`$arr = ['<img src="a"/>', '<img src="b"/>', '<img src="c"/>'];`

the expected output:

`hello <img src="a"/> wow <img src="b"/> cool <img src="c"/> yes!`

I can use `preg_match_all` to get the separator but still have no idea how to replace it respectively.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace_callback`. Store the number of the current full stop in a static variable. Access `$arr` from the callback with `use ()`. Use modulo in case there are not enough items in `$arr`.

```php
<?php
$content = 'hello . wow . cool . yes!';
$arr = ['<img src="a"/>', '<img src="b"/>', '<img src="c"/>'];
$content = preg_replace_callback ('/\./', function ($_) use ($arr) {
    static $count = 0;
    return $arr [$count++ % count ($arr)];
}, $content);
echo ($content);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f9115bdb6eb17e30012d987ed1fc4b95e7c10d33.