# How to replace strings in brackets with <span> tags in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, replace

I have thousands of string in a MySQL table in a column called query of type varchar(4096) which look always similar to the following one. The brackets are not always the same number! That means that in one query there could be 3 variables in brackets and in another on 7 variables in brackets.

**Sample**

```
“How can we compare the total rewards [team], taking into account that [industry] is better? Provide metrics for analysis, including [costs], and [best practices]. Additionally suggest any [potential areas for improvement] based on your analysis.”
```

What i want to do is to replace these brackets and put them in  where 1 should be counting for the amount of existing brackets:

**Expected result**

```
“How can we compare the total rewards <span class="variable-1">[team]</span>, taking into account that <span class="variable-2">[industry]</span> is better? Provide metrics for analysis, including <span class="variable-3">[costs]</span>, and <span class="variable-4">[best practices]</span>. Additionally suggest any <span class="variable-5">[potential areas for improvement]</span> based on your analysis.”
```

How can i do this directly within MySQL?

Comment: Adding the `<span>` is easy. Tricky part is, you seemingly want another classname for each replacement

Comment: the downvote is proably, because when asking a question, you are expected to show some effort how you tried to solve this yourself ...

Comment: Understood. But to be honest when it would be just about replacing a string in MySQL through SQL, then i would understood it. Just google for it and you have thousands of answers. But this is very special due to the count up. When i would have an idea, i would have already posted it.

Comment: Understood. But then you should have mentioned that in your question. This is how this site works. You don't just throw in your requirements and expect others to provide ready to use code. Explaing where your problem lies specifically ...

Comment: Do you have brackets that are not matched?  If so what do you want done with e.g. `foo[bar[baz]quux`?  How many sets of brackets does any one string have at most?  What does `select version();` show?

Comment: this is easily doable, but the details matter

Comment: Can you share your solution nonetheless, assuming brackets are correctly matched? @ysth

Comment: what does `select version();` show?  How many sets of brackets does any one string have at most?

Comment: @lemon this is very similar to dealing with columns with comma separated values but how to best do that depends on those things

Comment: @ysth: I can have max 10 strings within brackets within a db column of type varchar 4096. It is always guaranteed that i have only `[string]'. So no nested or corrupt ones. I have checked this now. The output of select version() is '5.7.37-nmm1-log'.

Comment: does the table have a primary key?

Comment: @ysth: No, yes. There is a id column as PK with AUTOINCREMENT. But i could disable it temporary.

Comment: no, the primary key is needed for this; see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following MySQL SQL googled:

```
SET @counter := 0;
UPDATE table1 SET prompt = REGEXP_REPLACE(columnA COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci, '\\[([^\\]]*)\\]', CONCAT('<span class="prompt-variable-', @counter := @counter + 1, '">', '\\1</span>'));
```

Seems to be a very slim and simple solution. Replace `table1` and `columnA`. It creates a variable named `counter`. With Regex it searched for brackets `[]` and add the html `span` around it.

Answer (score 1):

A compromise between efficiency and effectiveness, is assigning the name "*variable*" to all your variables, and then gather all variables with tools belonging to higher than sql layers. Attempting to assign a different id to each variable could lead you to some kind of recursive query, which would reveal highly inefficient (especially if you're dealing with thousands of strings).

Assuming having the same variable name could work for you as well, you can try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` with backreference. In order to make sure the matched text does not include other closed parentheses, we can use the lazy operator `?`.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, 
                      '\\[(.*?)\\]',
                      '<span class="variable">$1</span>') AS txt
FROM tab
```

If the pattern matching looks too relaxed due to '.*?', you can restrict your available values among brackets `[A-Za-z ]+?`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, 
                      '\\[([A-Za-z ]+?)\\]', 
                      '<span class="variable">$1</span>') AS txt
FROM tab;
```

or match any character except closed bracket `[^\\[]+`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, 
                      '\\[([^\\[]+)\\]', 
                      '<span class="variable">$1</span>') AS txt
FROM tab;
```

**Output**:

| txt |
| --- |
| How can we compare the total rewards <span class="variable">team</span>, taking into account that <span class="variable">industry</span> is better? Provide metrics for analysis, including <span class="variable">costs</span>, and <span class="variable">best practices</span>. Additionally suggest any <span class="variable">potential areas for improvement</span> based on your analysis. |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bfYpg3zvtzXmGGv6NTMYyf/0).

Comment: That always sets the same class `variable-1`. OP seems to want a different classname `variable-1`, `variable-2`, `variable-3` ... in every replacement

Comment: Updated with the limitation of this solution.

Comment: I think, and that was also another direction which i thought about, was to do this in PHP. Pure SQL would be much faster, but from solution perspective this does not to be possible.

Comment: If you want I can update the answer with the recursive query, but that may take you hours, maybe days to run, depending on the amount of data you have (and considering the size of your strings). On the other side, using this kind of regexp_replace solution is long way faster.

Comment: I have upvoted your solution. Thank you for your effort. I dont think that this makes sense. I will update this question + php solution.

Comment: I have found something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64383287/1595350 and try now to implement it and share the solution with the community.

Comment: Yeah, this solution in php looks definitely more viable than attempting doing it in sql.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a table foo with a column bar to change and an id primary key:

```
update foo
join (
    select id, group_concat(case when i then concat('<span class="variable-',i,'">[',replace(substring_index(substring_index(bar,'[',i+1),'[',-1),']',']</span>')) else substring_index(bar,'[',1) end order by i separator '') newbar
    from foo
    join (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10) i
        on i <= char_length(bar)-char_length(replace(bar,'[',''))
    group by id
) newbar using (id)
set bar=newbar
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xq7sYSlo)

This splits up each string based on the number of left brackets and adds the spans to each part beginning with a bracket, then rejoins them together.

`char_length...-char_length(replace...` is how you count the number of substrings in a string.

`substring_index(substring_index(...,delim,i+1),delim,-1)` is how you extract the ith part of a string delimited by delim.